# Difference Between Report Builder in SQL Server and Reporting Services in VS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Hey im trying to get my head around the following , what is the difference between Report Builder in SQL Server and Reporting Services in VS ?

They seem to have both different wizard design screens i.e. one built into SQL Server the other one you can build in Visual Studio....do they both have the same end results etc ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Report Builder is an end-user tool while the BI tools in Visual Studio are for the developer and can utilize the full capabilities of SSRS.

No, they don't have the same results. You can do vastly more with Visual Studio. Builder is primarily for very basic reports, though a user can get somewhat creative, but it's nowhere near the full capabilities that BI in VS unleashes.

Comment: Great thanks, Im watching tutorials in VS right and they building reports and look great when debugging etc..but how actually can you display these reports on a website or whatever in a live environment ?

Comment: @StevieB You can preview it within BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio, i.e. VS)

Comment: Yeah I got, I guess what im wondering lets say you build the report and preview looks perfect etc...what is the most comman way to actually deliver this report to a customer whatever i.e. how do they view this report ?

Comment: They will view it typically over the web using SSRS & SQL Server. There are plenty of other ways to view a report (which is actually an XML file) but that's the most common.

Comment: ok then last question how do would I actually display / deploy it to the web ?

Comment: You do it from the VS Build menu. It's Deploy. I know that's an oversimplification, but it's really not all that different from deploying a website when you think about it. It's just putting a file on a remote machine essentially.

Comment: hate to bump such an old thread, but what exactly are all these differences warranting the "vastly more" qualifier.  Other than the nuances of shared report parts and creation of report models (a feature deprecated in ssrs 2012) I can't really think of a whole lot